# Whats the name of this horror anime

Tags: umezu-kazuo-no-noroi

Here are all the details I remember:

It begins with a guy on a swing warning you to not mess with the supernatural.

Then the first story begins about a girl who is jealous of another girl in her class for being more beautiful than her. She is also having strange experiences in her sleep. She asks her friend to videotape her sleeping to find out what's wrong. The next day he looks at the videotape and she is extremely scared to look at it so he watches it himself, after watching it he is so disgusted that he tells her not to watch it. In the end she watches it and it is revealed that she is possessed by some sort of ancient Japanese jealousy demon and that she stole the beauty of the girl she was jealous of.

And then there's a second part about two girls watching horror movies, one is really scared the other isn't and they go out to an abandoned house for fun, on the way they meet two other girls who come with the crew too look at the house, in the end they invade some kind of demon that brutally kills all but one of them

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure I found what you're describing, in the quest to figure out what's the horror anime from late 80s/early 90s that I'm looking for.

From: http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=8211

The Curse of Kazuo Umezu
楳図かずおの呪い (Japanese)

Plot Summary: Two separate stories. In "What Will the Video Camera Reveal", a transfer student arrives from Mexico causing great agitation into the life of a classmate named Masami. In "The Haunted Mansion", four girls adventure into a sinister house on their neighborhood.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipIppmeQwf0